In Drupal 10 I want to use the hook_preprocess_menu_local_task to add fontawesome icons to the text output. How can I do this?
In Drupal 10 I want to use the hook_preprocess_menu_local_task to add fontawesome icons to the text output. How can or should I do this? I feel that I am close and just over looking something. Any help would great thanks!
I do see the icons in the $link_render_array variable. But nothing actually outputs. This is my code I have so far:
```
`/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for menu local task.
 */
function theme_preprocess_menu_local_task(array &$variables) {
  // Initialize.
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $link = $element['#link'];
  $link_text = $link['title'];
  $icon_html = '';

  // Define the icon HTML based on the link text.
  switch ($link_text) {
    case 'View':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> View';
      break;

    case 'Edit':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit';
      break;

    case 'Delete':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete';
      break;

    case 'Panelizer':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-table-columns" aria-hidden="true"></i> Panelizer';
      break;

    case 'Devel':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-gears" aria-hidden="true"></i> Devel';
      break;

    case 'Revisions':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Revisions';
      break;

    case 'Clone':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Clone';
      break;

    case 'Create':
      $icon_html = '<i class="fa-solid fa-file-lines" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create';
      break;
  }

  // Check if 'url' exists in the link array before using it.
  if (isset($link['url'])) {
    $link_url = $link['url'];

    // Create the render array for the link.
    $link_render_array = [
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => ['#markup' => $icon_html],
      '#url' => $link_url,
      '#attributes' => $link['localized_options']['attributes'] ?? [],
    ];

    // Ensure the href is respected in the anchor tag.
    $link_render_array['#options']['attributes']['href'] = $link['localized_options']['attributes']['href'] ?? '';

    // Render the link.
    $variables['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'li',
      'children' => $link_render_array,
    ];

    // Debugging information.
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($variables['content']);
    echo '</pre>';
  }

  // Attach the Font Awesome library.
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'sog/fontawesome';
}`
```

Fontawesome 6 is working on my site in other places. So I know that is not the issue. It seems that something is stripping the html out and sanitizing the output.
Displays var_dump of the previous code snippet.
I want an before each tabs text "icon Edit".
I have tried doing this in the twig template file as well, which results in none of the tabs outputting at all.
